# Is there any neat way to get pointer to data from vector of arrays?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a c-style array returned from third party function.

I need to initialize buffer with multiple copies of this array and then pass this buffer as a pointer to data to another third party function. E.g. if a segment is `{1, 3, 5, 8}` then the buffer should be `{1, 3, 5, 8, 1, 3, 5, 8, 1, 3, 5, 8}`.

Consider the following:

```
...
std::array <T, sizeOfSegment> segment;
...
std::vector<std::array<T, sizeOfSegment>> dataBuffer(countOfSegments, segment);
T* pData = dataBuffer.data()->data();
```

This looks like an ugly hack.
Is there any alternative way to get pointer to data, or, alternatively, to initialize vector by multiple blocks of data?

Size of both segment and dataBuffer are known at compile time.

What seems wrong to me is that data()->data() call returns pointer to the first instance of array<...>, yet I will be passing it as a pointer to whole buffer. 
While I know that this is correct because buffer is sequence of arrays, it just doesn't feels correct way... Am I wrong?

PS. Example as requested:

```
void ThirdParty::ProcessData(int* pData, size_t data_size);
...
const size_t sizeOfSegment = 4;
std::array<int, sizeOfSegment> segment = {1, 3, 5, 8};
const size_t countOfSegments = 3;
std::vector<std::array<int, sizeOfSegment>> dataBuffer(countOfSegments, segment);
int* pData = dataBuffer.data()->data();
ProcessData(pData, sizeOfSegment*countOfSegments);
...
```

Comment: Why does that look like an ugly hack? that gets you a pointer to the first segment of data, isn't that what you want?

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that what you are after is a flat buffer, and not a buffer of buffers?

Comment: What you mean by ugly? You can iterate the vector using std::for_each() to initialize the elements in the array.

Comment: Yes, flat buffer, not a buffer of buffers. E.g. segment is {1, 3, 5, 8} than buffer should be say {1, 3, 5, 8, 1, 3, 5, 8, 1, 3, 5, 8}. All sizes known at compile time.

Comment: @DmitriiMotorygin, it isn't clear enough what you want to achieve. Please edit your question and provide [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any alternative way to get pointer to data, or, alternatively, to initialize vector by multiple blocks of data?
>
> What seems wrong to me is that `data()->data()` call returns pointer to the first instance of `array<...>`, yet I will be passing it as a pointer to whole buffer. While I know that this is correct because buffer is sequence of arrays, it just doesn't feels correct way... Am I wrong?

Since you seem to be after a flat buffer, the well-defined way to get one is by declaring a `std::vector<T>`. You can't legally pun a buffer of `std::array<T, N>` with a `T*`. That just leads to undefined behavior.

Once you got that out of the way, the derivation of the vector is pretty straight forward and easily verifiable as correct.

```
std::vector<T> dataBuffer;
while(countOfSegments--) {
    dataBuffer.insert(dataBuffer.end(), segment.begin(), segment.end());
}
```